# Difference between clock_t and time_t or time(NULL) and clock()

Tags: c, time.h

I just write a c program  to print integer value on every one second as a exercise,this program print the integer after wait for one second before printing the next integer so the program take 5 seconds to finish the execution.I am using `clock_t` and `time()` as timer and it works but when I use `clock_t` and `clock` as timer it doesn't work.

As i know `time_t` and `time()` is the absolute time and using the seconds that elapsed since 1970.While `clock_t` and `clock()` use the time since program run.

This is the first code using `time_t` and `time(NULL)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
  int i;
  int sec=1;
  time_t start,end;

  start=time(NULL);

  for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
     time_t wait=sec+time(NULL);
     while(time(NULL) < wait) {}
     printf("%d\n",i);
  }
  end=time(NULL);
  printf("program take %d second\n",(unsigned int)difftime(end,start));
  return 0;
}
```

and this is the result when the program run:

```
1
2
3
4
5
program take 5 second
```

execution of the program exactly print the integers on every one second or wait one second
before printing the next integer

this is the second program using `clock_t` and `clock()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
   int sec=1;
   int i;
   clock_t start,end;

   start=clock();

   for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
       clock_t wait=sec*CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       while(clock ()<wait){}
       printf("%d\n",i);
   }

  end=clock();
  printf("the program take %lf second\n",(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the result of second program using `clock_t` and `clock()`

```
1
2 
3
4
5
the program take 0.998901 second
```

and after the execution it doesn't print exactly every one second but first wait for one second and then print all of the integers instead of wait for one second before print the next integer.

Please explain what happen to the second program and what exactly the difference between 
time() and clock() function?

Comment: `time()` reports real time (typically in seconds since 1970). `clock()` reports CPU time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first program, this:

```
time_t wait=sec+time(NULL);
```

causes `wait` to change every time through the loop, becoming one second later than the current time (on systems where `time_t` is measured in seconds, at least, which is common, but not required).

In your second program, this:

```
clock_t wait=sec*CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

has the same value every time you execute it, since the value of `sec` never changes. So in your second program, the loop will wait on the first iteration until one second past program start, and on the subsequent iterations will never wait again, because more than one second will have passed since program start and `clock() < wait` will never again be true.

In short, your two loops really aren't even close to doing the same thing, so there's no reason you'd expect them to behave in similar ways. If you changed:

```
clock_t wait=sec*CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

to:

```
clock_t wait = i * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

then you might get something closer to what you're expecting.

Comment: I want to ask again.I assign the value of clock to new variable `clock_t now=clock` and then I changed the while loop to

Comment: I want ask again.I assign the value of `clock()` to new variable called `now` like this: `clock_t now=clock()` and then I changed the while loop `while(now < wait)`.After doing this,the program is able to run but cannot display the value of integer on each iteration.

does the value of `clock()' is the same as new variable `now`?

Comment: You really need to ask a new question, I can't really make much sense out of what you're asking. If you do `clock_t now = clock()` then obviously the value of `now` equals the return value from `clock()` at that time. But a nanosecond later - or whatever the resolution of `clock()` is on your system - it won't be, because `clock()` will have moved on, but `now` will not.